# Increment a integer field in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, pipeline

I am using logstash to upload logs into elasticsearch. Could I increment a field in my .conf file?

For example, I have a field 'count = 0;'
I hope to increment it to 1 when meet some conditions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are writing the output configuration for elasticsearch you will need to specify

```
"script=>script_name"
"script_lang=>groovy" (if you are using groovy)
```

and write a script which will check your condition and update the fields if the condition is satisfied. You can check [Event Dependent Configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html)  and [script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-script) option in elasticsearch for reference.